# Fail to transfer OSX TimeMachine backups from a current backup drive to a new backup drive

Tags: macos, backup, external-hard-drive, raid, time-machine

This was my mac osx scenario: Time Machine was using a RAID set (2 external hd of 1Tb each).

I wanted to expand the RAID set with an extra 1Tb disk without loosing my old backups, so I followed this article: https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202380?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Then what I did is:

- Backed up original Time Machine drive content in another drive
- Delete old RAID set
- Create a new RAID set from original 2 drives plus another 1Tb one, so the new RAID set is 3Tb
- Copied original Backups.backupdb folder to new RAID set drive
- Open TimeMachine preferences, selected new drive

Time Machine sees no last or recent backup

If I ***open*** Time Machine I can see the side little bars with the old backups but cannot move into them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem ...it wasn't a problem.

It seems that Time Machine does not see recent backups until the first new backup is completed.

I was frustrated but I decided to activate anyway TM.

And then after the first backup everything went ok, all the recent were there, about two months.